# How to print only specific columns based on a cell condition in Python Pandas (dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to print the columns "**COrder_ID**" and "**Supplier_Name**" only for the rows, which *contain* the word "Expired" in the column "**Reviews**".

I am using the following code to identify the corresponding rows, which contain the word "Expired" in the column "Reviews":

```
df[df['Reviews'].str.contains('Expired')]
```

This is the result:
[Result when executing the code]

[image: 1]

I know I can create a new dataframe out of the code above and print only the needed columns separately, but is there a more elegant way (iteration / "IF" statement) to achieve my goal?

Comment: `mask = [df['Reviews'].str.contains('Expired')]; df.loc[mask,["COrder_ID","Supplier_Name"]]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wwii thanks. Unfortunately I am getting a weird error after executing the df.loc statement and I haven't found a solution yet. "KeyError: "None of [Index([(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False)], dtype='object')] are in the [index]""